# Clearing log files located in var/log (RHEL)

Tags: cron, logs, gitlab

I am investigating the retention of logs in var/log/ for a server that hosts Gitlab.
There are multiple logs here as listed below:
Boot.log
Cron
maillog
Messages
Secure
spooler
yum.log

Is there a way that I can control the retention of these logs?
Is there anything that's controlled via the gitlab.rb file?
Is there a general way of identifying where logs are controlled?

Comment: Google: logrotate Google: Gitlab log rotation

Answer (score 1):

Look at `logrotate.conf` manual pages (a.k.a. man pages). You can use `logrotate` which is part of the base RHEL install.

[Here](https://linuxconfig.org/logrotate) is a tutorial with examples.